# init anchor project cause problem with rust-analyzer

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust

I'm just beginning with anchor by init new project but every derived trait causes a warning like so. It's said: "proc macro `declare_id` not expanded: crate has not (yet) been built".

[image: annoying warnning1]

Answer (score 2):

Gm fam.

Here is a link to the problem: https://fasterthanli.me/articles/proc-macro-support-in-rust-analyzer-for-nightly-rustc-versions

Solution 1)

Add to your rust-analyzer extension settings.json the following line.

```
"rust-analyzer.diagnostics.disabled": ["unresolved-proc-macro"]
```

If you don't know how to get to your extension's setting's .json, go to rust-analyzer's extension settings, top right click the icon that looks like a paper with an arrow. now add the line above.

Solution 2)

Add the following line instead of solution 1:

```
"rust-analyzer.diagnostics.enable": false,
```

This is not recommended as it'll disable all diagnostics.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the required crate isn't installed yet.

Try running `cargo run` or `cargo build`